# Sending SMS message using Nexmo, failed when using private network

Tags: php, html, vonage

My code is working when I am using a direct internet (open network). but when I tried to use a private network (which i am currently using in my company) I am getting this error.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\Files\xampp\xampp\htdocs\nexmo\src\NexmoMessage.php on line 228

Below is my code for sending the message..

```
<?php

    include ( "src/NexmoMessage.php" );

    if(isset($_POST['sendMessage'])){
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $message = $_POST['smsMessage'];

        // Step 1: Declare new NexmoMessage.
        $nexmo_sms = new NexmoMessage('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx');
        // Step 2: Use sendText( $to, $from, $message ) method to send a message. 
        $info = $nexmo_sms->sendText( $to, 'NexmoWorks', $message );
        // Step 3: Display an overview of the message
        //echo $nexmo_sms->displayOverview($info);

        // Done!
    }
?>
```

and below is the code where i am having an error.

```
     foreach($obj as $key => $val){
        // If we come across another class/array, normalise it
        if ($val instanceof stdClass || is_array($val)) {
            $val = $this->normaliseKeys($val);
        }

        // Replace any unwanted characters in they key name
        if ($is_obj) {
            $new_obj->{str_replace('-', '', $key)} = $val;
        } else {
            $new_obj[str_replace('-', '', $key)] = $val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you have used 2 different servers? If so error_reporting (php.net/error_reporting) is probably defaulting to two different values.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @PeterM i used two different network. one is the open network or direct internet, and the other one is the network that we are using within our company, we actually have to use our network in the company to make this work, but it fails so i tried it using direct internet just to know if there is something wrong with my code or with the internet we are using..